# Is it possible to use the Linux CLI to move and rename duplicates at the same time?

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, file-transfer, overwrite

I'd like to know if it's possible to move/copy files using the command line and automatically rename conflicting files? I scoured the forums and found different suggestions but none of them worked. So far I've tried:

1. `cp -r --backup=t /path/to/source /path/to/target`
2. `cp --backup=numbered /path/to/source /path/to/target`
3. `cp -R --backup=existing --suffix=.orig -t /path/to/source /path/to/target`

It's a large folder (700GB) which contains a lot of old files. The third command "kinda" worked (on some files), but I noticed that it didn't work on certain other files, since I left the PC on tonight to transfer the files and checked if it had overwritten anything (which it had).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: maybe the solution to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832363/rename-duplicate-files-when-using-scp-secure-copy) would be the easiest way to go (based on rsync)? Otherwise, I would suggest a custom shell script that loops through each file in source-dir and checks for a file with that name in target-dir, and adds a counter-suffix to the filename if it already exists...

Comment: @jov14: `rsync -b` is worth an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I found `cp --archive --backup --suffix="-original" A/* B` but this overwrites the file if there already is an `-original` - is there any way to make it copy files incrementally? Like: `example.txt`, `example.txt.original`, `example.txt.original.1`, `.2` and so forth?

Comment: I asked a friend of mine if `cp` was able to perform such a task, but he told me that I would need to script loops in order for `cp` to be able to do so.

Thanks for the help everyone.